emulate UART with QEMU aarch64 for raspberry pi 4
I followed https://github.com/s-matyukevich/raspberry-pi-os/blob/master/docs/lesson01/rpi-os.md to run my first kernel for aarch64 for raspberry pi. I built it and put kernel8.img into image taken from https://downloads.raspberrypi.com/raspios_full_arm64/images/raspios_full_arm64-2024-07-04/.
To run QEMU I used the following command:
emu-system-aarch64 \
        -machine raspi4b \
        -cpu cortex-a72 \
        -smp 4 -m 2G \
        -dtb bcm2711-rpi-4-b.dtb \
        -drive format=raw,file=2024-07-04-raspios-bookworm-arm64-full.img

In QEMU I see only black screen, I googled and found Qemu baremetal emulation - how to view UART output?, actually neither -semihosting --semihosting-config enable=on,target=native nor -serial mon:stdio work for me, screen is still black.
I also tried command:
qemu-system-aarch64 -M raspi4b \
    -display none \
    -serial null \
    -serial stdio \
    -kernel kernel8.img

from How to print a something in miniUART in Qemu (raspi3b)?, that also doesn't work. I suppose the code is valid, because I didn't change it, literally cloned from github.
In gdb I can see that QEMU executes instructions, but when I use -kernel option with raw binary, QEMU doesn't even start executing kernel_main it is lost itself somewhere in between. Though when I use ELF binary it starts executing kernel_main but loops in uart_send with the first character (H) and nothing happens in console, same happens when I boot it with -sd option.
UPD1:
I found that if I boot it with -sd option (the kernel is copied into image) it loops on UART initialization put32(AUX_MU_IER_REG,0);, where AUX_MU_IER_REG = PBASE+0x00215044 and PBASE = 0x3F000000, I have no idea why that is happening.
UPD2:
Well, I found that register bases and offsets for auxiliary and GPIO registers are different for raspi4b and raspi3b, so the code linked above isn't expected to run on raspi4b. This code still outputs the same if I use raspi3b, so I still have no idea why that doesn't work. I missed the output, code linked above actually works with raspi3b, so the rest of the problem is to adopt the code for raspi4b.
P.S.:
QEMU version:
$ qemu-system-aarch64 --version
QEMU emulator version 9.0.2
Copyright (c) 2003-2024 Fabrice Bellard and the QEMU Project developers

What  is wrong in the command above? How can I can check if QEMU does emulate UART and how can I check its output?
P.S2.: I don't want -machine virt, because it is generic, I want to emulate exactly -machine raspi4b.

@NateEldredge, 0x7e000000 is wrong, RPi4 maps peripherals to 0xfe000000 (this is PBASE as well), especially in "Low peripheral" mode, as BCM2711 states and this is the default mode as far as I understood from https://github.com/babbleberry/rpi4-osdev/issues/13. It also handles GPIO Pull-up/down in a different way

Try to add -append "earlycon=pl011,mmio32,0xfe201000 console=ttyAMA0,115200"
qemu-system-aarch64 --version
QEMU emulator version 9.0.50 (v9.0.0-265-gfd87be1dad)
Copyright (c) 2003-2024 Fabrice Bellard and the QEMU Project developers

qemu-system-aarch64 -M raspi4b -serial mon:stdio -nographic -kernel kernel8.img -dtb bcm2711-rpi-4-b.dtb -append "earlycon=pl011,mmio32,0xfe201000 console=ttyAMA0,115200"

[    0.000000] Booting Linux on physical CPU 0x0000000000 [0x410fd083]
[    0.000000] Linux version 6.6.44-v8+ (dom@buildbot) (aarch64-linux-gnu-gcc (Ubuntu 11.4.0-1ubuntu1~22.04) 11.4.0, GNU ld (GNU Binutils for Ubuntu) 2.38) #1790 SMP PREEMPT Mon Aug  5 16:07:01 BST 2024
[    0.000000] KASLR disabled due to lack of seed
[    0.000000] Machine model: Raspberry Pi 4 Model B
[    0.000000] earlycon: pl11 at MMIO32 0x00000000fe201000 (options '')
[    0.000000] printk: bootconsole [pl11] enabled
[    0.000000] efi: UEFI not found.
[    0.000000] Reserved memory: created CMA memory pool at 0x000000002c000000, size 64 MiB
[    0.000000] OF: reserved mem: initialized node linux,cma, compatible id shared-dma-pool
[    0.000000] OF: reserved mem: 0x000000002c000000..0x000000002fffffff (65536 KiB) map reusable linux,cma
[    0.000000] Zone ranges:
[    0.000000]   DMA      [mem 0x0000000000000000-0x000000003bffffff]
[    0.000000]   DMA32    empty
[    0.000000]   Normal   empty
...
[    3.679878] Memory Limit: none
[    3.680988] ---[ end Kernel panic - not syncing: VFS: Unable to mount root fs on unknown-block(0,0) ]---


Thank you for contributing to the Stack Overflow community. This may be a correct answer, but it’d be really useful to provide additional explanation of your code so developers can understand your reasoning. This is especially useful for new developers who aren’t as familiar with the syntax or struggling to understand the concepts. Would you kindly [edit] your answer to include additional details for the benefit of the community?

qemu-system-aarch64 \
-M raspi4b \
-initrd ~/VMs/rpi4/initramfs8 \
-serial mon:stdio \
-nographic \
-kernel ~/VMs/rpi4/kernel8.img \
-dtb ~/VMs/rpi4/bcm2711-rpi-4-b.dtb \
-append "earlycon=pl011,mmio32,0xfe201000 console=ttyAMA1,115200 root=PARTUUID=57b902f5-02 rootwait" \
-sd ~/VMs/rpi4/resized.img 

$ xz -d 2024-11-19-raspios-bookworm-armhf-full.img.xz
cp 2024-11-19-raspios-bookworm-armhf-full.img resize.img
You'll need to mount that image (there are two partitions) and extract bcm2711-rpi-4-b.dtb and kernel8.img. See the answer above as args to qemu-system-aarch64 reference these two files.
$ qemu-img resize resize.img 16G
WIP

I can't get graphics to work

I compiled 9.2.50 from source, I dunno about the stock qemu on, say, Ubuntu.
